# Restoring a program window when it is highlighted (turns red on Windows 10)

Tags: autohotkey

When a program is open, but minimized to the taskbar, and a new message is received, it will blink red/orange.

I am trying to detect when a message is received (or an action/event caused by it) and `WinRestore` after a two second delay.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try the command ControlGet or ControlGetFocus for this window.

Comment: Check if the Window title or other detectable parameters change. Like a "(1)" at the title for a new message.